# Using electromagnetic fields to achieve an unbreakable blade

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, science-fiction

A while ago I stumbled upon the idea of a stasis field, which shined the light in the tunnel for a question I have. Let's assume that a character has the magical ability to control electricity, could he then achieve a stasis-like effect where the object he is manipulating will become almost indestructible? Are there any smarter ways on going about this?

I do not necessarily wish for the accompanying time-stopping and reflecting properties.

Edit: Excuse if it isn't clear. I am talking about the plausibility of the question within the limitations of the physical laws (obviousky excluding the electrokinesis part).

Comment: If his ability is magical, as you say, then it can do whatever you want.

Comment: If it's good enough for the *Known Space* series (take a look at the Variable Sword), it's probably good enough for a fantasy universe.

Comment: this really depends on what a stasis field is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matter is kept together by electromagnetic fields.

Diamonds are so though because of the electromagnetic fields resulting from the spatial arrangement and mutual interaction of all the carbon atoms and their electrons in the diamond crystal lattice.

But diamonds get broken at a certain point. So does any material, simply because any force can be overcome by a greater one.

The only thing which we know it can't be broken is black holes, but they are held together by gravity and they can't be broken because somehow there is a speed limit in the fundamental laws of our universe (nothing can travel faster than light).

The above if you want to stay within science. If you want to use magic, magic can do anything, even turning a toad into a charming prince.

Comment: In any practical sense, I wouldn't be ashamed with neutron stars either. At least they don't evaporate :grin:

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, neutronium might have the funny tendency to dramatically expand if you take it out of the neutron star

Comment: Well, about that taking it out of the neutron star, what can I say? *In any practical sense*, "good luck with that" seems appropriate

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, I can imagine the protocol for any astronaut landing there: be sure to clean your shoes before entering the ship. Any grain of neutronium dust will be a huge problem on lift off :D

Comment: True, I always let a doormat behind in such cases. A good thing my cargohold is large enough to fit enough for a lifetime :grin:

Answer (score 1):

A stasis field as depicted in science fiction does not really have any real life-counter part. From the Wikipedia article [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stasis_(fiction) ], a list of science fiction interpretations of a Stasis field are given and I'm assuming the effects you are envisioning are similar to the ones given here.

You give the caveats that you do not want the common effects of time dilation (usually depicted as stopping completely) and reflecting. However, time stoppage is the reason that things in stasis fields are depicted as making objects indestructible.

As Dutch elegantly explains, physics simply doesn't allow for the electromagnetic interaction to convert an object to an indestructible one. There is no physical phenomena which corresponds to a stasis field, and although the idea appears in Science fiction is is just as magical as *mana*.

The association in Sci-fi of electromagnetic fields being able to create a "stasis field" comes from an old misunderstanding of the Electromagnetic interaction that was prevalent before the proliferation of the theory of General Relativity (GR). GR demonstrated that Gravity could be expressed as a geometric theory in which mass changes the geometry of Space-Time. Prior to this theory, the special nature of light and its speed were recognized though not understood, and there were many attempts to express space-time as a electromagnetic phenomena. Relics of this can be found today with reference to the "Aether"; the universal medium. Linking electromagnetic interactions to teleportation or the speeding up/slowing down in time and even time travel can be found in science fiction and fanciful conspiracy theories (see Nikola Tesla or The Philadelphia Experiment).

Thus stasis fields as an EM phenomena, while not physically possible as known by modern science can be seen as a relic of a bygone era of physics based science fiction.